# How can I delete a Hotmail account from the Email app on Android 4.4.2?

Tags: email, accounts

I want to remove a Hotmail account that I added to the Email app in Android 4.4.2. I do not see a 'Remove account' option anywhere in the app. How do I do this?

Comment: Well I could do it : app>all>email>clear cached data. It removed all email accounts from email app, and then I added which I wanted to keep.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! It's perfectly fine here at SE to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17845/192154), and you're even encouraged to do so. Nobody expects an answer to be hidden in a comment. So may I suggest you make your comment an answer, and later "accept" it by ticking the check-mark next to it? That makes it perfectly clear to everybody here this problem has a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [OP's comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/87171/how-can-i-delete-a-hotmail-account-from-the-email-app-on-android-4-4-2#comment110407_87171), you have to clear Email's cached data:

1. Go to Settings - Apps
2. Choose "All" tab
3. Find and open "Email"
4. Click "Clear Cache", this will remove all email accounts used on the app.
5. Re-add the accounts that you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

On my Android phone, I had to do this:

Settings →Accounts → select the account you want to delete (by tapping it) → tap on the 3 vertical dots menu → select Remove Account.

Answer (score 0):

if above techniques are not working for your mobile then go to apps -> all -> go to exchange which is having the same symbol as email and tap the clear data. your email account will be removed :)

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings>accounts>email>your account>remove account